# SAS 9.1 - SAS Server Main vs. Local Libraries

Tags: shared-libraries, sas

I'm working on an older SAS server (Running 9.1).  Other users of the system strictly use this SAS server; however, I have a need to transfer data between this and the local SAS Server.  When invoking any LIBNAME statements, the actual path of the SAS server is listed and therefore it fails to resolve LIBNAME foo 'c:\mypathname\foo'; and instead seems to regard this as LIBNAME foo '/server/longerpath/c:\mypathname\foo'.  I do have a handful of paths on the sas server LIBNAME bar 'serverpath\bar' that I am using as well.  Is it possible to access both the local sas library as well as the sasMain server library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running code on the server, unless you have SAS/CONNECT (are using RSUBMIT), you will need to give the server the path to access your local machine as if you were not on it - that may be impossible, or you may have a UNC path, like \machinename\c$\foo\ , that you can access it with.

If you're using RSUBMIT, then you can access the server's libraries (including work) using the `server=` option on `libname` from your local machine prior to the rsubmit, and/or `PROC DOWNLOAD` or `PROC UPLOAD`.